# Can someone explain to me what this Array Java program wants me to do?

Tags: java, arrays

I am stuck on this one problem on Arrays. I haven't started the program yet because I really don't understand what it wants me to do! Here is the problem:

**Write a method called wordLengths that accepts a String representing a file name as its argument. Your method should open the given file, count the number of letters in each token in the file, and output a result diagram of how many words contain each number of letters. For example, the following text:**

> Before sorting:
>
> 12 23 480 -18 75
>
> hello how are you feeling today
>
> After sorting:
>
> -18 13 23 75 480
>
> are feeling hello how today you

**your method should produce the following output to the console:**

```
1: 0    

2: 6    [There should be 6 * printed here]

3: 10   [There should be 10 * printed here]

4: 0

5: 5    [There should be 5 * printed here]

6: 1    [There should be 1 * printed here]

7: 2    [There should be 2 * printed here]

8: 2    [There should be 2 * printed here]
```

So StackOverflow is rather limited, so I wasn't able to show you the full style of the output, but in summary, the "Before Sorting:"  part that is followed by 2 sentences are one group, "After sorting:" and the 2 sentences below are another group. The "before" and "after" sorting are separated by one space.

I don't get how the output is achieved, that's my problem. I have a feeling that the 1-8 represents line numbers, but what do the 0, 6, 10, etc. represent? Because when I counted the word lengths, they exceeded 6 or 10...
It'd be a great help if someone could explain to me what this program wants me to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - 8 are length of a word (or a number, or a token); -18 has length 3, and "sorting:" is 8.

0, 6, 10... are the number of occurrences for words that have the length 1, 2, 3...

BTW, this is not really a question fitting here but hope this could help.

Answer (score 1):

According to this....

**Write a method called wordLengths that accepts a String representing a file name as its argument. Your method should open the given file, count the number of letters in each token in the file, and output a result diagram of how many words contain each number of letters. For example, the following text:**

We break this down into several steps.....

```
A   Write a method called word Lengths 
B   that accepts a String representing a file name as its argument. 
C   Your method should open the given file, 
D   count the number of letters in each token in the file, 
E   and output a result diagram of how many words contain each number of letters. 
F   For example, the following text:
```

## TEXT

```
Before sorting:
12 23 480 -18 75
hello how are you feeling today
After sorting:
-18 13 23 75 480
are feeling hello how today you
```

Falls into the following ideology...

1 is 0 because
No words contain 1 letter

2 is 6 because
Six words contain TWO letters (12 23 75 13 23 75)

3 is 10 because
Ten words contain THREE letters (480 -18 how are you -18 480 are how you)

4 is 0 because
No words contain FOUR letters

5 is 5 because
Five words contain FIVE letters (hello today after hello today)

6 is 1 because
One word contains SIX letters (before)

7 is 2 because
Two words contain SEVEN letters (feeling feeling)

8 is 2 because 
Two words contain EIGHT letters (sorting: sorting:)